# How to make Dynamic TextBox in C#

Tags: c#

I have simple FormApplication script that contains button and some TextBoxs.
I want when click on button, one textbox shows some numbers.
How I can make that dynamic.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txt3.Text = "";
     for (int i = 0; i <50; i++)
     {
         Random random = new Random();
         int randomNumber = random.Next(100, 150);
         txt3.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
     }
}
```

Now it waits to loop finished and shows latest number.
I want it shows each number during loop in TextBox seperatly.
Seems using Dynamic TextBox is a bit hard, is there any other solution to show this numbers in main form?
Regards,

Comment: That loop will finish very quickly, do you want it to have a delay between each number?

Comment: I added timer but not works.

Comment: Add your updated code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now it waits to loop finished and shows latest number.

That's because the operation is single-threaded so there's no UI update until it's completed.  How you would change that depends on whether this is a Windows application or a Web application.

If this is, for example, a Windows Forms application then you want to call `Application.DoEvents()` to update the UI each time the loop iterates:

```
txt3.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
Application.DoEvents();
```

This will update the UI's text box each time.  (Though it will be *very* fast, so I doubt you'll even notice it.  You might throw in a `Thread.Sleep()` if you want to slow it down.)

If this is a web application, then you'll want to do this whole thing client-side instead of server-side.  This is because "updating the UI" in a web application, at least from the server's perspective, means returning the response and waiting for another request.  This would result in a lot of back-and-forth between the browser and the server just for updating a single UI element.  (Which, while it would be slow enough that you'd notice it, it would be a terrible UX.)  So in this case you'd want to move the code to JavaScript, which has the benefit of not being single-threaded and would update the UI as you expect it to.

Comment: is it smart to do Thread.Sleep() in the UI thread? also what does Application.DoEvents(); exactly?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: It's not, no.  The other answers regarding timers and separate threads are better design, I just thought I'd provide another answer the OP might find helpful.  I think `Application.DoEvents()` was what the OP was really looking for, not any kind of threading or delaying.  For something as simple as this, it tends to get the job done well enough.  All it does it act as sort of an interrupt in the code to cycle through UI events (re-drawing, responding to input, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

you need to do it in separate thread and sleep between each iteration or use a timer.

for example:

```
private int counter;
Timer t = new Timer();
Random random = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     t.Interval = 100;
         t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
         counter = 0;
         t.Enabled = true;
     txt3.Text = "";
}

  void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     counter++;
     int randomNumber = random.Next(100, 150);
     txt3.Text = randomNumber.ToString();

     if (counter >= 50)
     {
        t.Enabled = false;
     }
  }
```

remember this is just one example out of million ways to do it. a lot of them are good

another way will be using threads:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(randomize));
     t.Start();
}

  private void randomize()
  {
     Random random = new Random();

     txt3.Text = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
     {
        int randomNumber = random.Next(100, 150);

        Invoke(new setTxtHandler(setText), randomNumber.ToString());

        Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
  }

  private void setText(string val)
  {
     txt3.Text = val;         
  }

  private delegate void setTxtHandler(string val);
```

Comment: @user1955534 one thing though, make sure it's System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `Random` outside of the loop since it is seeded with the current time and the loop executes too fast.

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i <50; i++)
{
    int randomNumber = random.Next(100, 150);
    txt3.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
}
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.random.aspx)

> The random number generation **starts from a seed** value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the **same series of numbers is generated**. One
>   way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value
>   time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new
>   instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the
>   Random class **uses the system clock to generate its seed value**, while
>   its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the
>   number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has
>   finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create
>   different Random objects in close succession creates random number
>   generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.

However, since the loop executes very fast you won't see each value anyway, only the last.

Comment: I don't think this will change what OP is seeing, the textbox will still just show the last number (the other numbers will go by too quickly).

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: Yes, you're right. It's not really clear what OP is trying to achieve. If he wants to update a TextBox to report progress he should use a `BackGroundWorker` and it's appropriate events to update the UI-thread. However, that would also be too fast to be noticed, so he needs some kind of delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a panel and then add textboxes onto it

```
  Random random = new Random();
     for (int i = 0; i <50; i++)
     {
         TextBox t=new TextBox();
         int randomNumber = random.Next(100, 150);
         t.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
    panel.Controls.Add(t);
     }
```

Comment: Tried Panel, but this Hide TextBox

Comment: No it wont. If it does, maybe you should check your css.

Answer (score 0):

You should you separate thread and calculate numbers there and update UI then, because now your UI will be updated after calculation is finished.

E.g. [BackgroundWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show each number in the text box, you will need an additional thread which will run the code you have inside button1_Click. With your current implementation, the GUI will freeze while executing the content. As it's very quick you won't notice it though.
From the additional thread, call invoke when setting txt3 to synchronize with the GUI thread. And add a Thread.Sleep(1000) or similar in the for loop in order to see the numbers change.